# Get the average rating of the current category

Tags: magento-1.9, category, ratings

I'm new to magento and i'm currently working on the CE1.9 for work.
I'm having trouble to get the average rating of the current category.

```
$category_id = Mage::getModel('catalog/layer')->getCurrentCategory()->getId();
$category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($category_id);
$products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()->addAttributeToSelect('*')->addCategoryFilter($category)->load();

$reviews = array();

foreach ($products as $product) {
    $productId = $product->getId();
    array_push($reviews, Mage::getModel('review/review')
            ->getResourceCollection()
            ->addStoreFilter(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId())
            ->addEntityFilter('product', $productId)
            ->addStatusFilter(Mage_Review_Model_Review::STATUS_APPROVED)
            ->setDateOrder()
            ->addRateVotes()
    );
}


foreach ($reviews as $review) {
    $_votes = $review->getRatingVotes()->getFirstItem();
    if($_votes->
    $totalRating += $_votes->getFirstItem()->getValue();
}
Zend_debug::dump(100 * $totalRating / (5 * $reviews));
```

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I solved it myself.

For those interested, here is the code:

```
    $categoryId = Mage::getModel('catalog/layer')->getCurrentCategory()->getId();
    $currentCategory = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($categoryId);
    $productList = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()->addAttributeToSelect('*')->addCategoryFilter($currentCategory)->load();
    $reviewList = array();
    $storeId = Mage::app()->getStore()->getId();
    foreach ($productList as $product) {
        $summaryData = Mage::getModel('review/review_summary')->setStoreId($storeId)->load($product->getEntityID());
        $reviewData[] = $summaryData['rating_summary'] / 20;
    }
    $nbReview = 0;
    foreach ($reviewData as $review) {
        if ($review != Null)
            $nbReviews++;
            $totalReviewIntoStar += $review;
    }
    return $AvgRating = $totalReviewIntoStar / $nbReviews;
```